# How to export Eclipse IDE created file as image

Tags: images, java, eclipse, export, ide

Is there is a way for a file, `.java` for example, created in the Eclipse IDE to get exported as an image?

Comment: What do you mean as an image?  Do you just want a screen shot of the source?

Comment: @ernie: Yes, but when I take a screenshot, the resolution is not good. I was wondering if there is way to export the file as an image that keeps the resolution as it is.

Comment: How are you currently getting your screenshot?  what OS?  Most screenshot programs will capture at the same resolution as the screen, so your question seems confusing?

Comment: @ernia: print screen is giving better resolution but it required me to do the cropping work at my end. Windows 7.

Comment: Alt-PrtScn will get you the active window.  If you want just the text panel, you'll likely need to turn to third-party screenshot tools.